# Specify function interface in template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that forwards a function:

```
template <class T>
class Foo{
  template <typename Func, typename... Args>
  void Bar(Func function, Args&&... args) {
   T t;
   (t->*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  } 
}
```

This works, but is there any way to check whether `Func` is contained in the interface of `T`, so `T::Func`? Now, if I enter a wrong function the compiler would complain that `t->*function` doesn't exist, but I would like to specify in the function interface that it should be a `T::Func`. However I can't seem to get the syntax for this right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really necessary to specify this in the signature, since it will fail to compile for the wrong cases anyway, but you could specify member function pointers like this:

```
template <class T>
class Foo{
public:
  template <typename Func, typename... Args>
  void Bar(Func T::*function, Args&&... args) {
   T t;
   (t.*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  } 
};
```

And to call it:

```
struct S
{
    void func(int) {}
};
void freeFunc(int) {}

int main()
{
    Foo<S> f;
    f.Bar(&S::func, 42); //OK
    //f.Bar(&freeFunc, 42); //ERROR
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/shr7561Ex)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This is very helpful in auto type deduction, though.